# Why kernel of map betwwen to tensor products should be$J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In this PhD thesis [Convolution on homogeneous spaces](https://research.rug.nl/en/publications/convolution-on-homogeneous-spaces) there is this theorem in chapter 1 at page 9

" Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a unital ring, and let $\mathbf{V}$ be a right $\mathbf{R}$ - module, and $\mathbf{W}$ a left $\mathbf{R}$-module.

Let $\mathbf{P}$ be a subring of $\mathbf{R}$, containing $1$ .

Let $\mathbf{J}$ be the additive subspace of $\mathrm{V}\underset{\mathbf{P}}\otimes \mathrm{W}$ generated by elements of the form
$$
vr\underset{\mathrm{P}}{\otimes}w-v\underset{\mathrm{P}}{\otimes} rw,
$$
$v \in V, w \in W, r \in R .$

Then $\mathrm{V}\underset{R}\otimes \mathrm{W}$ is isomorphic (as an additive space) to $(\mathrm{V}\underset{R}\otimes \mathrm{W}) / \mathrm{J}$.

**Proof** Let $\tau^{R}$ be the canonical map $ V \times W \longrightarrow \mathrm{V}\underset{\mathbf{P}}\otimes \mathrm{W}$. This map is bi-additive and $R$-balanced, and therefore a fortiori $\mathrm{P}$ - balanced. So, there exists an additive map $\ell: \mathrm{V}\underset{\mathbf{P}}\otimes \mathrm{W} \longrightarrow \mathrm{V}\underset{\mathbf{}}\otimes \mathrm{W}$ such that $\ell(v\underset{\mathrm{P}}{\otimes}w)=v\underset{\mathrm{R}}{\otimes}w$. It remains to be shown that the kernel of $\ell$ equals $J$ ..."

Then the author proofs the isomorphism and conclude that the kernel of $\ell$ equals $J$.

My question is why do we need that the kernel of $\ell$ equals $J$?

Comment: You are missing / misplacing some subscripts below $\otimes$, e.g. the codomain of $\ell$ should be over $R$, and the superscript of $\tau$ should be maybe $P$. Nevertheless, we simply want to use the *first isomorphism theorem* which states exactly $A/\ker f\cong{\rm im\,}f\le B$ for any homomorphism $f:A\to B$.